# Local Notification to trigger at specified time

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a meeting object , which contains endtime of the meeting ,it has  present meeting/future meeting , i want to send notification to the user when meeting time end with respect to time , i am getting the end time from the json and saving it to realm database, but problem is that when my service run i get one  notification at a current time(means as i open the app) but it's end time is different .Here i gave my best :

In the Service : onStartCommannd

```
 realmResults= realm.where(MeetingsModel.class).findAll();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalBroadCastReceiver.class);

    if(realmResults!=null && realmResults.size()>0){
        for(int i=0;i<realmResults.size();i++){
            // here i am getting endTime of meeting
            String timeStampEnd=realmResults.get(i).getTimestampEnd();
            try {
                calendar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(timeStampEnd));
                long tempEndDate=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                // setting my endTime
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(tempEndDate);
                    // unique id for every meeting
                    intent.putExtra("OBJECT_ID", realmResults.get(i).getId());


            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    MeetingsModel specificPerson = realm.where(MeetingsModel.class)
            .equalTo("meetingId", intent.getIntExtra("OBJECT_ID",-1))
            .findFirst();
    Log.e("getId---",""+specificPerson.getId() + "----"+calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getBaseContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

    // pending intent with unique id
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), specificPerson.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    // here i am getting endTime of meeting which should trigger when meeting end
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

BroadcastReceiver :

```
// receiving the intent from the service
        MeetingsModel specificPerson = realm.where(MeetingsModel.class)
                .equalTo("meetingId", intent.getIntExtra("OBJECT_ID",-1))
                .findFirst();

        // Here i  am getting all the id of the meeting
        Log.e("specificPerson-",""+specificPerson.getId());

        // Prepare notification title and text
        String title = "Flowace App";
        String text = "Meeting END Time";

        // Prepare notification intent
        // MainActivity is the class that will be opened when user clicks on notification
        Intent intentAction = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        // Notification should get created with same pending intent that sent from the service
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, specificPerson.getId(), intentAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Send notification (I have a static method in NotificationHelper)
        NotificationHelper.createAndSendNotification(context, title, text, pendingNotificationIntent,specificPerson.getId());
```

Comment: Why you are setting alarmManager in a loop?

Comment: because endtime is different so calendar should set to different endtime

Comment: You have to cancel the previous alarm before setting

Comment: @AbhayBohra I had edited my code still i am facing the same issue , now i am getting one notification as soon as i open the app . but it's end time is different

Comment: When your end time passed you should cancel the alarm immediately using its pending intent request code